# USB pin connection to the circuit

Tags: usb

In my circuit I have USB connector for data transmission from MCU to PC. There are the next scheme of USB connection in datasheet (http://naviawireless.ru/wp-content/uploads/pn6280_hardware-design_v1.0.pdf) on my module. I don't understand, where i should connect power supply pin, if I should.
The module is powered by 3.8 V, that comes from stabilization chip from 5 V. Should i connect power supply pin of USB with this 5 V?[image]

Comment: If you have an external power supply already, you should not connect it to the 5V coming from the PC. Alternatively you hav just power the whole thing from PC, but how do you want it to work? The MCU might need info from the power pin to know that PC is connected, but we have no idea what you are doing and how do you want it to work.

Comment: Gleb - Hi, (a) You seem to be saying there is something you don't understand on a datasheet, but you only included one small part of it. Please [Edit] your question and link to the whole datasheet. (b) Please add more context. What is the project? (c) You *seem* to be asking whether you should output 5 V onto USB. Please [Edit] the question and clarify. (d) That partial schematic (and use of 3.8 V) reminds me of GSM / LTE modules, but you mention a microcontroller. Again, your overall project and its power source(s) need to be clarified by you, if you are asking us where / how to supply power.

Comment: @SamGibson, Hi. The entire circuit is powered from an external 5V source, which is reduced to 3.8V through a stabilizer to power the module. A USB port is also required for data exchange with a PC. The document contains a diagram that I have attached, but I do not understand where to connect the power to this port.

Comment: @Gleb - Thanks for adding the link to the datasheet and your comment, which helped clarify the question. No, you do not connected your external 5V supply to the USB VBUS. After your additional clarification, I now see your question is a duplicate of [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/455822/should-i-connect-the-computer-vbus-line-to-the-5v-line-of-the-board) previous question, so I have closed it as a duplicate of that one. You can read more details there. Thanks.